# Electron HTML Javascript button not working

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I'm trying to create and save files using javascript.
This is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Tutorial</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.con/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css"> 
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" id="form-container">
<textarea class= "form-control" placeholder ="File Contents..." rows="10"></textarea>
<input id= "content" class="form-control" placeholder="Input Text Here...">
<button id="createButton" class="btn btn-success">Create File</button>
</div>
</body>

<script>
    require('./renderer.js')
</script>
</html>
```

[image: Create File button not working]
The page looks like this currently. For some reason I don't understand, the button to create file doesn't work I click it but nothing happens. It does not create a file, nor does it open a location where you want to save the file.

This is my Javascript code:

```
var app = require('electron').remote;
var dialog = app.dialog;
var fs = require('fs');

document.getElementbyId('createButton').onclick = () => {
    dialog.showSaveDialog((fileName) => {
        if(fileName === undefined){
            alert("You didnt save the file");
            return;
        }

        var content = document.getElementbyId('content').value;
        fs.writeFile(FileName, content, (err) => {
            if(err) console.log(err);
            alert("The file has been succesfully saved")
        })
    });
};
```

Why won't the 'Create File' button work?

Comment: Look at your console on renderer side (`webContents.openDevTools`). It says "Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementbyId is not a function". That's all.

Answer (score 0):

The function you are trying to use is called `document.getElementById`, using the [camel-case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) naming convention. Your code would look like this, when corrected:

```
//... require statements as in your code
document.getElementById("createButton").onclick = () => {
    // ...
    var content = document.getElementById("content").value;
    // ...
}
```